# Wordpress.com "code blocks": special characters like dplyr pipe (%>%) causing errant display

Tags: r, wordpress, dplyr, wordpress.com

I am trying to show R code on my wordpress.com blog but the code is being distorted when I preview or publish. This particularly happens with the dplyr pipe function (%>%), of which I lose the percent and greater than sign sometimes.

For example, this:
[code language="r"]
library(dplyr)
tester <- mtcars %>% head(5) %>%
             pull(cyl)
[/code]

becomes the following (missing ">%" after `tester`):
`library(dplyr)
tester % head(5) %>%
             pull(cyl)`

Even using the `<pre>` tag referenced in the Wordpress ["Writing Code in Your Posts"](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts) article caused some distortion, despite this tag purportedly causing the browser to "exactly reproduce whatever is inside of the  tags".

Comment: You should read the whole codex page you are referring to ... _"Using the `<code>` tag doesn't tell WordPress to encode HTML markup within the tag or strip it from the post. WordPress thinks that you are using this markup for formatting, leaving it untouched. [...] To avoid this behavior, [use character entities or extended characters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Fun_Character_Entities) to represent the left and right arrow characters"_

Comment: _"despite this tag purportedly causing the browser to 'exactly reproduce whatever is inside of the tags'"_ - codex says, _"Every space, line break, every bit of code is exactly reproduced."_ - the first two are correct, that's what the `pre` element is for - showing pre-formatted (text) content, formatting referring to use of white space and line breaks; the last part about "bits of code" is rather nonsense. Same as with a `textarea`, while putting unescaped HTML tags into it might work to a certain extent, it is certainly not correct.

Comment: Switching between "Visual" and "Text" mode should help though, copy&paste the HTML code (in actual "text" form, not some already WYSIWIG-ed or MS WORD-saved as HTML-crap) in in visual mode, switch over to text mode to manually add the `<pre>` tags around it ...

Comment: The prism plugin does a dandy-job rendering R code. https://wordpress.org/plugins/prism-highlight/

Comment: @hrbrmstr, good to know. I may switch to hosting a wordpress.org blog one day but the question references wordpress.com "host-for-me" blogs.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code to a Github Gist at https://gist.github.com/.

Then insert the entire Gist URL (starts with `https://gist.github.com/`) for the webpage displaying your code (has your Github ID name at the top and an embed block at the top you will not use) into the HTML section of your code on its own line. For example:
`This is some text. And now here is some code:
https://gist.github.com/RickPack/f159e1b35b096f5325ac7093652d4b2e`

Placing the Gist URL into the HTML section of your Wordpress.com post will cause Wordpress to display the code associated with your Gist in an attractive fashion rather than the URL. While your particular language's syntax highlighting may not be preserved, at least there is no loss of characters.